# How to know that an iPhone that I purchased from a third-party is not JailBroken?

Tags: iphone, security, jailbreak

Say, I purchased an iPhone (not from Apple or any official reseller.)

How do I know that it's not Jailbroken?

PS. My concern is the presence of key loggers or other tracking software.

Comment: Just restore it with iTunes when you get it, and you'll be good.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson: That "answer" that you linked to doesn't actually have an answer.

Comment: Yes, I know, but this question is still a duplicate of that question, and duplicates are linked/merged so that when someone *does* answer the question, they don't have to answer it in 6 different places.

Comment: So far this entire discussion is really missing the point entirely. If you just got a 'new' phone the first thing to do is wipe it & start afresh. Until you do, nothing on it belongs to you; you can't even tell if it's activation locked. Once you've nuke & paved it, it *cannot* be jailbroken any more, even if it was in the first place.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Sure. But as I said in one of the comments below, I can't use iTunes to wipe it. But when I wipe the phone from the settings, there's no guarantee that the wipe is thorough. (As it can be faked by the software already on the phone.)

Comment: Then, I'm afraid there's no way round that. You won't have iTunes, you don't trust the phone. Throw it away.

Comment: @c00000fd I posted an answer to the question this was marked a duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

Not being familiar with jailbroken phones I can't offer a "what to look for" hint but really all you have to do is hook it up to iTunes and reinstall the latest OS update.

Comment: Thanks. That's something. Unfortunately I don't use iTunes. It's an awful software (especially on Windows.) So I'm **not really** looking forward to installing it again. Instead I was hoping for some official Apple app that I can download to test it?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to go into Settings>General>About and scroll down until you see *Serial Number*. Apple has a verification website [Here](https://checkcoverage.apple.com) to determine if the iPhone you bought is authentic. All you have to do is enter your *Serial Number*. If it comes back with

> "We're sorry, but this serial number is not valid."

Then your phone is non-authentic and fake.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for the app named Cydia, you can use Spotlight to search for it. It is a standard app that's installed once iOS has been jailbroken and it cannot be deleted nor uninstalled.